Issue with Arabic Letters ﻻ in Substrings Using Keyboard Key B
When typing in Arabic on Ubuntu Linux, there is a conflict with the two letters ﻻ when they appear in a substring. Instead of displaying together as in the word "حلا," they appear as "حﻻ." This issue is specifically caused by using the keyboard key B in Arabic, which corresponds to ﻻ. However, when the letters are typed separately as g and h (لا), the issue does not occur.
OS: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS x86_64 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Host: HP Z600 Workstation 
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Kernel: 6.5.0-41-generic 
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Uptime: 35 mins 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Packages: 2625 (dpkg), 6 (flatpak), 21 (snap) 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Shell: bash 5.2.21 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Resolution: 1920x1080 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   DE: GNOME 46.0 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM: Mutter 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   WM Theme: Adwaita 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Theme: Yaru-dark [GTK2/3] 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/    Icons: Yaru [GTK2/3] 
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+     Terminal: gnome-terminal 
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/      CPU: Intel Xeon X5675 (24) @ 3.060GHz 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 6GB 
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-         Memory: 7603MiB / 56209MiB 



You'll need to provide Ubuntu product (Ubuntu Core? Ubuntu Server? Ubuntu Desktop?) and release details.  Do you have a question, as I only see a statement.

I'm sorry, I added the details

You've still not said what you want to achieve....   If you're trying to report a bug, this isn't a bug tracker but a support site.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

It is good that this is being first put on AskUbuntu as a question.  Far too many first time contributors assume their problem is a bug.

Voted to close this one, same page with guiverc and quill. I just wanted to add, you need to collect more info about it before making bug report: Test another editor, Test another font with full Arabic script support (nowadays, fonts can borrow from each other missing glyphs, not easy to troubleshoot)
